# How to store all the value of 1st array returned by firebase in php

Tags: php, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose i have data under db **user**

```
{
  "signup_login" : {
    "2315218123" : {
      "name" : "yohan",
    },
    "2665451854" : {
      "name" : "Ram",
    },
    "5453698463" : {
      "name" : "Raj",
    }
  }
}
```

as i have tried this piece of code to retrieve the data of **signup_login** under the database **user**

```
class lol  {
    protected $database;
    protected $dbname = 'signup_login';

    public function __construct(){
        $acc = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__ . '/secret/user-key.json');
        $firebase = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount($acc)->create();

        $this->database = $firebase->getDatabase();
    }

    public function get(){

        if ($this->database->getReference($this->dbname)->getSnapshot()){
            return $this->database->getReference($this->dbname)->getValue();
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}

$users = new lol();
var_dump($users->get());
```

as i want to store data in form of array like

```
$data = ["2315218123","2665451854","5453698463"]
```

but the code written above is returning this as a output as its right but i would like to store it in form of array mentioned above but i am unable to do it..

```
array(3) {
  [2315218123]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "yohan"
  }
  [2665451854]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "Ram"
  }
  [5453698463]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "Raj"
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your example, you could get the IDs with [`array_keys()`](https://php.net/array_keys):

```php
$lol = new lol();
$userIds = array_keys($users->get());
var_dump($userIds);
```

PHP converts integer strings to integers when using arrays, so you would have to convert the values to string afterwards:

```php
$userIds = array_map('strval', $userIds);
```

Some notes:

You're apparently using the [Firebase Admin SDK for PHP](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php), but with methods that have been deprecated since a long time. I'd like to suggest you update to the latest version (4.40 at the time of this writing) and follow the documentation at https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/.

Instead of writing

```php
$acc = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__ . '/secret/user-key.json');
$firebase = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount($acc)->create();
$database = $firebase->getDatabase();
```

you should use

```php
$acc = __DIR__ . '/secret/user-key.json';
$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount($acc);
$database = $factory->createDatabase();
```

In your example, you are calling `getSnapshot()` and `getValue()` separately - please note that this will cause two separate calls to the Firebase API (`Database::getValue()` is just a convenience shortcut for `Database::getSnapshot()->getValue()`)

A more efficient way to retrieve the keys in your reference would be to use the `Reference::getChildKeys()` method.

In light of all this I'd like to suggest that you rewrite your `lol` class to something like this:

```
class LolWut
{
    /** @var \Kreait\Firebase\Database\Reference */
    private $ref;

    public function __construct($refName = 'signup_login')
    {
        $this->ref = (new Factory())
            ->withServiceAccount(__DIR__ . '/secret/user-key.json')
            ->createDatabase()
            ->getReference($refName); // Does not invoke a call to the Firebase APIs
    }

    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->ref->getSnapshot()->getValue();
    }

    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getUserIds(): array
    {
        return array_map('strval', $this->ref->getChildKeys());
    }
}
```

It would also be a good idea to instantiate the factory outside your class and only pass to your class what you need inside of it to operate.

I hope this helps!